# Configure postfix on Xubuntu for xampp php send mail

Tags: postfix

i have got a nasty problem:

For web developing i have a:

- oracle virtualbox
- xubuntu 10.04 lts in a
- xampp for Linux 1.7.3a

Configured with several virtual hosts for offline-testing my websites. 
For developing / designing E-Mails i need an e-mail server. I want simply to send mails from my websites and see them in an e-mail - client in virtualbox. no sending e-mails to  outside the virtualbox.

So i installed postfix.

But i simply cant get it to work. Now i test with a simple joomla E-Mail Form (phpmailer). But it cant connect to my smtp. Logfiles say:

### mail.info:

```
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: warning: ::1: address not listed for hostname localhost
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: connect from unknown[::1]
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: lost connection after RSET from unknown[::1]
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: disconnect from unknown[::1]
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: warning: ::1: address not listed for hostname localhost
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: connect from unknown[::1]
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: lost connection after RSET from unknown[::1]
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: disconnect from unknown[::1]
```

### mail.warn:

```
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: warning: ::1: address not listed for hostname localhost
Nov  8 19:24:51 joe-desktop postfix/smtpd[4221]: warning: ::1: address not listed for hostname localhost
```

postfix doesnt know `::1`? but it should. here my configuration files:

### hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test1
127.0.0.1 test2
127.0.1.1 joe-desktop
127.0.0.1 xampp
127.0.0.1 test3
127.0.0.1 test4

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

### And in main.cf:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mydestination = joe-desktop, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

I installed webmin to configure postfix. in webmin i can send & receive mails. so postfix should run.

I'm searching now for hours, i hope someone can help me. But I must admit i am really not a linux pro.
I hope someone can help me. 
Bye, Mojo

Comment: Personally, I would go with exim4.  The configuration system will get you a working setup by default, and a lot of basic config can be done by running `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`.  Postfix theoretically should be just as easy, but I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment. 
I solved the problem, i turned off authentification and now sending to joe@localhost works.

One further question.

If I send i.e. to "tester@mydomain.de" postfix says in log:

Recipient address rejected: mydomain.de

ist it possible that smtp accepts E-Mails to all receipients / all domains and relays them to joe@localhost?

Does s.o. know how to configure that?

The system runs in a virtualbox without internet-connection. so spam is no problem.

Bye, Mojo

Comment: Answers are not designed to ask questions. Nobody will answer.